# Android Lollipop device not recognised by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to run my app from Android Studio on a physical device running Lollipop (5.0.2), but neither the choose device dialog nor the adb manager can recognise it. In fact, the only place on the PC I can see it is in the device manager (it does not show up as a drive).

I have tried all the usual solutions with updating the driver and such, but nothing helps.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer, for me, was to change USB-port *to a USB 2 port*.

It does not work on USB 3 ports.

Comment: How do I change to a USB 2?

Comment: You physically move the USB cable to another USB-port on your computer, one that is black in the middle, not blue (the usual way to show that it is a USB 3 port).

Answer (score 1):

I have just been having this issue. [This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93168/android-5-0-lollipop-device-not-detected-via-usb) led me to the right answer.

On my machine, for one of the USB ports the device would install but wouldn't be recognised by adb. For another port the driver installation would fail.

The following steps worked:

1. Go to device manager and find the device (with the orange triangle)
2. Right click > Update driver software
3. Browse my computer for driver software
4. Browse to the USB driver folder in the Android SDK (see below)
5. Click next etc

This time the driver installed correctly and adb recognised the device.

Driver folder:

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver
```